# path based proxy with http-proxy nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-http-proxy

I want a proxy with path based routing.
But my code not working

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy')

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxy();

var options = {
'example.com/app1': 'http://localhost:4444',
'example.com/app2': 'http://localhost:3333'
}

require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {
proxy.web(req, res, {
    target: options[req.headers.host]
},function(error) {

});
}).listen(80);
```

How is the problem?

Thanks for Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the latest version of http-proxy dropped the proxytable feature. see https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/blob/master/UPGRADING.md
the version 0.8.x can do path based routing. And for current http-proxy, a middleware can do proxytable for it (https://github.com/dominictarr/proxy-by-url)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try [express-http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-http-proxy) which let you mount the proxy on a express route:

```
app.use('/app1/', proxy('http://localhost:4444', {
    forwardPath: function(req, res){
      return url.parse(req.url).path.replace(/\/app1/,'/');
    }
  })
);
```

Even though you asked for a node.js solution, I can't really suggest to go with this route (no pun intended). 
You're probably better off with something which have been tested more with this specific use case - like nginx:

```
location /app1/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:4444;
}
```